# Two different viewports for ipad's portrait and landscape views

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there a way to specify two different viewports, one for portrait and one for landscape mode, in the ipad?

I have a page that seem to be needing two different values for things to look ok. Is this possible?

I need (in portrait mode):
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7, maximum-scale=1.0"

And (in landscape):
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple conditional

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
    self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    // do stuff for portrait
} else {
    // do other stuff for landscape
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. In the "do other stuff for landscape section" I tried to modify the content attribute of the meta tag, but it didn't help, is it because I was too late and the page was already loaded?

Comment: @cabrera: Possibly. You can try calling `setNeedsDisplay` or resetting values within `shouldAutorotate...`